# FutureWarning about encoding from to_excel Pandas

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, encoding, future-warning

My code:

```
df.to_excel('sheet.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
```

The error message:

> FutureWarning: the 'encoding' keyword is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Please take steps to stop the use of
> 'encoding'

How can I replace the 'encoding'?

Answer (score 1):

`encoding` got deprecated because it seems to be unused. There is no alternative.

- [Changelog](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#other-deprecations)
- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/47912)